# What is the difference between 2006 Nissan Altima (baseline) and SE-R taillights?

Tags: nissan, tail-lights

I've noticed that [a lot vendors are marketing lights as SE-R.](http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/05-06-NISSAN-ALTIMA-EXC-SE-R-TAIL-LIGHT-LAMP-PAIR-/280709076254?pt=Motors_Car_Truck_Parts_Accessories&fits=Year%3A2006%7CMake%3ANissan%7CModel%3AAltima&hash=item415b90951e#ht_3243wt_995) I know SE-R is the sports trim but what's the differences between their taillights and the other trim levels?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mechanics :)

Comment: It has to do with motor vehicle repair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same tail light except the SE-R tail lights have black surrounding the lights behind the lens instead of chrome like the regular models.